# user control inherits from custom control

Tags: asp.net, controls

I have an custom control that extend System.Web.UI.UserControl. Is it possible to inherit user control from this custom control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So long as you have not marked the control as `sealed`, you can inhrit from it and create other user controls that use the functionality already written.

So long as `UserControl` is part of the inheritance chain, everything should work as you would expect.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Simply swap out your custom UserControl class in your user control's code-behind. All that is necessary is that the base user control derive from `System.Web.UI.UserControl` as you describe.

```
public partial class MyUserControl : MyBaseUserControl
{
    // ...
}
```

If you are not using a code-behind, you can use the `Inherits` attribute in the `<%@ Control %>` directive to specify the base class.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in fact is very useful as you can have common methods available for all of your controls through this inherited custom control. It is that standard practice in our shop that no control inherits directly from System.Web.UI.UserControl but from the extended control in our common library.